# Importing React Autosuggest as Functional Component from Another JSX File

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently making a simple web frontend with react using react-autosuggest to search a specified user from a list. I want to try and use the Autosuggest to give suggestion when the user's type in the query in the search field; the suggestion will be based on username of github profiles taken from github user API.

What I want to do is to separate the AutoSuggest.jsx and then import it into Main.jsx then render the Main.jsx in App.js, however it keeps giving me 'TypeError: _ref2 is undefined' and always refer to my onChange function of AutoSuggest.jsx as the problem.

Below is my App.js code:

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from './views/header/Header';
import Main from './views/main/Main';
import Footer from './views/footer/Footer';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
      <Main/> <- the autosuggest is imported in here
      <Footer/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is my Main.jsx code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import AutoSuggest from '../../components/AutoSuggest';

const Main = () => {
    const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/users?per_page=100')
        .then((res) => setUserList(res.data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, [])

    return (
        <Container>
            <br/>
            <Row>
                <AutoSuggest userList={userList} placeHolderText={'wow'} />
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

Below is my AutoSuggest.jsx code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';

function escapeRegexCharacters(str) {
    return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

function getSuggestions(value, userList) {
    const escapedValue = escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());

    if (escapedValue === '') {
        return [];
    }

    const regex = new RegExp('^' + escapedValue, 'i');

    return userList.filter(user => regex.test(user.login));
    }

    function getSuggestionValue(suggestion) {
    return suggestion.name;
}

function renderSuggestion(suggestion) {
    return (
        <span>{suggestion.name}</span>
    );
}

const AutoSuggest = ({userList, placeHolderText}) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

    const onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) => { <- error from console always refer here, I'm not quite sure how to handle it..
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    const onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
        setValue(getSuggestions(value, userList))
    };

    const onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
        setSuggestions([]);
    };

    const inputProps = {
        placeholder: placeHolderText,
        value,
        onChange: () => onChange()
    };

    return (
        <Autosuggest 
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={() => onSuggestionsFetchRequested()}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={() => onSuggestionsClearRequested()}
        getSuggestionValue={() => getSuggestionValue()}
        renderSuggestion={() => renderSuggestion()}
        inputProps={inputProps} />
    );
}

export default AutoSuggest;
```

The error on browser (Firefox) console:

[image: type error _ref2 is undefined]

I have no idea what does the error mean or how it happened and therefore unable to do any workaround.. I also want to ask if what I do here is already considered a good practice or not and maybe some inputs on what I can improve as well to make my code cleaner and web faster. Any input is highly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have to write it like this... do not use the arrow function in inputProps

```
        onChange: onChange
```